# Do we really need film/TV Show/Franchise tags in meta?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta

I noticed that here on meta there are many Film/TV show and franchise tags, like:

[star-wars](/questions/tagged/star-wars)

[star-trek](/questions/tagged/star-trek)

[disney-star-wars](/questions/tagged/disney-star-wars)

On the main site they make sense but do we really need them on meta too?

Comment: At the very least, [disney-star-wars] is pretty redundant when [star-wars] already exists.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Fair enough; merged those two. (Even if we do end up getting rid of all of them, that'll be easier the fewer tags we have to search for.)

Comment: Although I disagree, the consensus here is reasonably clear, so I've gone ahead and nuked the tags in question. (This had the side-effect of remapping their 'followers' to the [meta-tag:discussion] tag, so there will probably now be some irritated people getting notified about every `discussion` question rather than just `star-wars` or `star-trek` questions. But so be it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## NO.

Meta is the place to discuss [the workings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) of the site itself. Inherently questions on Meta are *not* about a franchise or work.

This is why Meta has one of four required tags (support, feature request, bug, and discussion).

Comment: But those questions on meta are not (or should not be) about the franchise or work _itself_, they are about the tag or the tagged questions on the main stack and as such _are_ about the workings of the site.

Answer (score -3):

### Yes

**But not because of the *franchise*.**

We tag questions on meta with tags that describe what the question is about. That's what tagging is for.

For some of the larger or more complex tags on the main stack, the need can arise to discuss these main stack tags (or the questions in it). Examples of these indeed include [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) and [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), which both have numerous sub-tags and thousands of questions, but also [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), which *isn't* a franchise, but still has a meta co-tag for its main stack tag.

This does not mean that *every* tag on the main stack should have meta counterpart, nor that every "large" tag on the main stack (for varying definitions of "large") should have one.

Only those main stack tags that are begin discussed on meta in several questions, *may* find a co-tag on meta useful.

Answer (score -4):

### Yes, because these tags do reflect common topics of *meta* discussion.

Sometimes meta questions are specifically about a particular franchise, even requiring expertise in that franchise in order to be answered: see for instance [Star Wars/Canon/Disney Revisions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3311/31394) or [Which canonicity is more right in a Legends question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8064/31394) in the [star-wars](/questions/tagged/star-wars) tag. Just as issues surrounding story-ID often need special consideration that other tags don't (hence not only our [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag on meta but also [similar tags on other sites' metas](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify)), so might issues surrounding, for instance, Star Wars or Star Trek. These massive franchises, taking up a large proportion of questions on the main site, are valid topics of meta discussion for our community.

Besides, what harm do these tags do?

Comment: So rule made for Star Wars will be different then Star Trek in meta?

Comment: @JonSnow Yes, obviously. For example, Star Wars has its own canonicity rules which are different from Star Trek's. Discussion about when to use the [tag:star-wars-legends] tag, for instance, are specific to this franchise and irrelevant to all others.

Comment: But we don't tag meta question with everything we can, it should be relevant. I mean on other SE sites we don't do that

Comment: @JonSnow How is [meta-tag:star-wars] not "relevant" to a question about how we should handle Star Wars canonicity issues on SFF.SE? And other SE sites do use meta tags associated with particular main-site tags; I even linked to an example in this answer, from the site where you're a mod.

Comment: Identify tag is not a Film/TV show and franchise tags and if you didn't noticed my question is not about [tag:story-identification] tag

Comment: @JonSnow no, but I agree with Rand al'Thor that might want to discuss "large" tags from the main stack; [meta-tag:story-identification] is another example of such a tag.